# BizTalk : Consuming WCF Service - There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline

Tags: web-services, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am creating a sample biztalk application which consumes a WCFService for learning purpose. I had no problem in consuming the WCF Service and using that to in BizTalk Application in which I give an input xml file in the input folder and and an Output xml file is generated in the output folder.

Now I am trying to do give the input to the WCF Service via a sample applcation I am getting an error which says

> There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline:
>   "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive,
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Send Port:
>   "******Send Port Name****"
>   URI: "*********" Reason: No
>   Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.

I am using the wcf-custom adapter for binding. What could be the error here?

Answer (score 4):

The error you are receiving lets you know that the message you received (indeed, the response) is not valid according to any *known* schema within your BizTalk application domain. Try and setup WCF tracing/diagnostics to see what exactly your web service is responding. Most likely, if this is a SOAP-bases web service for example, it might be a typed SOAP fault.

Valuable links:

Diagnostic Tracing and Message Logging - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185303(v=bts.10).aspx

How to Handle Typed Fault Contracts in Orchestrations - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246117.aspx

Best practices for handling web service exceptions in BizTalk Server - http://www.codit.eu/blog/2012/01/13/best-practices-for-handling-web-service-exceptions-in-biztalk-server/

Comment: You can also set AllowUnrecognizedMessage=True on the receive pipeline of the send port (or use the PassThruReceive pipeline) to have BizTalk not raise an error, and allow you to inspect the content of the received message.

Comment: You can also enable failed message routing and route the failed messages somewhere (ESB exception DB or just a file send port that filters on failed messages).